# How to implement RSA encrypt and decrypt in Java

Tags: java, rsa

I have the public and private key generation working. My next step is to create 2 more methods - encrypt and decrypt. I'm just not sure about how to implement the encrypt and decrypt. I have a few ideas, but nothing that seems to be a good solution. Any insights?

```
public class RSA
{
    private final static BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    private final static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    // prime numbers
    private BigInteger p;
    private BigInteger q;

    // modulus
    private BigInteger n;

    // totient
    private BigInteger t;

    // public key
    private BigInteger e;

    // private key
    private BigInteger d;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class RSA
     */
    public RSA(int N)
    {
        p = BigInteger.probablePrime(N/2, random);
        q = BigInteger.probablePrime(N/2, random);

        // initialising modulus
        n = p.multiply(q);

        // initialising t by euclid's totient function (p-1)(q-1)
        t = (p.subtract(one)).multiply(q.subtract(one));

        // initialising public key ~ 65537 is common public key
        e = new BigInteger("65537");
    }

    public int generatePrivateKey()
    {
         d = e.modInverse(t);
         return d.intValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your private key generation function may fail. As an exercise, determine why. HINT: It will fail approximately with prob = 2/65537. Also, `d.intValue()` is a meaningless quantity.

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven't really asked a specific question, I'll offer you a somewhat tangential answer.

DIY Crypto is famously a bit like DIY nuclear power.

I recommend reading [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) if you want to learn about crypto coding, and using it rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking, but for RSA crypto, if your modulus is *n* bits wide, your public key will also be *n* bits wide. A simple `int` won't work.

**See also**

My own humble attempt at RSA encryption in Java:
http://david.tribble.com/src/java/tribble/crypto/RSACipher.java